# Is “instead of me” used correctly?

Tags: phrase-usage

Suppose I have a doctor’s appointment and I want to give it to my sister. I want to ask my doctor if it is OK. Is using “instead of me” correct?

> I have an appointment on Friday. Can my sister come instead of me?

Are there any better alternatives to that?

Comment: Although the expression you suggest is common, **....come in my place** or **take my place/appointment** might be better alternatives. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-someone-s-place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely fine.

> I should have let her come **instead of me**. I knew she wanted to come.
>
> You can go **instead of me**, if you want.

You could also use *in place of somebody* or *in somebody's place*:

> I'm going to lead the meeting **in place of Janet** because she went home sick.
>
> He was unable to go to the ceremony, but he sent his son **in his place**.
>
> When her manager fell ill, she was asked to attend the sales conference **in his place**.